# Unable to process multiple events in Azure Logic App with 'For each' loop and 'items()' function

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I am developing an Azure Logic App to handle notifications for several events (near expiry, expired) on Azure Key Vaults. My setup involves an Event Grid for each Key Vault, all sending their events to the same Logic App.

When Event Grid sends events to the Logic App, they come as an array of events. I am trying to use a 'For each' loop in my Logic App to process each of these events individually. Here's the relevant portion of my Logic App:

I have a 'When a HTTP request is received' trigger,
Followed by a 'For each' loop with triggerBody() as the input,
Inside the loop, I have a 'Send an email (V2)' action.
In the 'Send an email (V2)' action, I'm trying to access the properties of each event using the items() function like this: [image]

```
Event Type: @{items()?['eventType']}
Key Vault Name: @{items()?['data']?['VaultName']}
Object Type: @{items()?['data']?['ObjectType']}
Object Name: @{items()?['data']?['ObjectName']}
Expiry Date: @{items()?['data']?['EXP']}
```

But when I try to save the Logic App, I get this error message:

`Failed to save logic app. The template validation failed: 'The template action 'Send_an_email_(V2)' at line '1' and column '1679' is not valid: "The template language function 'items' must have at least one parameter.".'.`

I have reviewed the documentation and understand that items() doesn't require a parameter when used inside a 'For each' loop, as it automatically refers to the current item of the array that 'For each' is looping through.

What am I doing wrong? How can I set up my Logic App to correctly process each event individually using a 'For each' loop and the items() function?

Below is my schema input:

```
{
    "schema": {
        "properties": {
            "$schema": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "properties": {
                "properties": {
                    "data": {
                        "properties": {
                            "properties": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "EXP": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "Id": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "NBF": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "ObjectName": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "ObjectType": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "VaultName": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "Version": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "required": {
                                "items": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "type": "array"
                            },
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "dataVersion": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "eventTime": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "eventType": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "metadataVersion": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "subject": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    "topic": {
                        "properties": {
                            "type": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "type": "object"
            },
            "required": {
                "items": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "type": "array"
            },
            "type": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "object"
    }
}
```

sample of the output:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5a",
        "topic": "/subscriptions/8",
        "subject": "kv",
        "eventType": "Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNearExpiry",
        "data": {
            "Id": "https://kv",
            "VaultName": "kv-v",
            "ObjectType": "Secret",
            "ObjectName": "kv",
            "Version": "",
            "NBF": null,
            "EXP": "2023-06-13T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "dataVersion": "1",
        "metadataVersion": "1",
        "eventTime": "2023-06-12T00:00:00Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample input ?

Comment: @Shiva Patpi. Thanks for the help. I just updated my question with the input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have tried to reproduce the issue by using one logic app for 2 key vaults and individual event grids for each key vaults subscribing multiple event types-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**These two key vaults publishing events to single logic app-**

[image]

Here in "Select an output from Previous steps", I am taking `triggerBody()`.

[image]

```
Event Id: @{items('For_each')?['id']}, 
Event Type: @{items('For_each')?['eventType']}, 
Subject: @{items('For_each')?['subject']}, 
Key Vault Name: @{items('For_each')?['data']?['VaultName']}, 
Object Type: @{items('For_each')?['data']?['ObjectType']}, 
Object Name: @{items('For_each')?['data']?['ObjectName']}
```

**Request Body**-

```
{
"items": {
"properties": {
"data": {
"properties": {
"EXP": {
"type": "string"
},
"Id": {
"type": "string"
},
"NBF": {
"type": "string"
},
"ObjectName": {
"type": "string"
},
"ObjectType": {
"type": "string"
},
"VaultName": {
"type": "string"
},
"Version": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"type": "object"
},
"dataVersion": {
"type": "string"
},
"eventTime": {
"type": "string"
},
"eventType": {
"type": "string"
},
"id": {
"type": "string"
},
"metadataVersion": {
"type": "string"
},
"subject": {
"type": "string"
},
"topic": {
"type": "string"
}
},
"type": "object"
},
"type": "array"
}
```

**Output which I am getting is**-

```
[
{
"id": "0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"topic": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/iafrin-xxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/afreen-key-002",
"subject": "afreenSecret001",
"eventType": "Microsoft.KeyVault.SecretNearExpiry",
"data": {
"Id": "https://afreen-key-002.vault.azure.net/secrets/afreenSecret001/xxxxxxxxxx",
"VaultName": "afreen-key-002",
"ObjectType": "Secret",
"ObjectName": "afreenSecret001",
"Version": "yyyyyyyyyyy",
"NBF": null,
"EXP": "2023-06-14T05:20:00Z"
},
"dataVersion": "1",
"metadataVersion": "1",
"eventTime": "2023-06-14T05:19:56.9159226Z"
}
]
```

**I am getting email notification for all the subscribed event types**-

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, with your setup do you need a logic app per each key vault or no? My setup uses only one logic app and event grid per each key vault. so I don't think this will work in my case.

Comment: Yes, my setup also needs one logic app per each key vault

Comment: Try to use items(For_each) instead of items() in @{items()?['eventType']}

Comment: sorry I meant to say I have only one logic app for all my 50 KV whereas I have an event grid per each KV. so I don't think it will work here. I tried items(For_each) with my current setup. didn't work either.

Comment: modified my answer as per your requirement, have a look